# RegEx to match lowercase and numerics, of at least a certain length, and only the whole word

Tags: regex

I need to match a 1-30 characters string containing only ascii letters and digits. It should not match at all if it isn't the entire word.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
(\b[a-z0-9]{1,30}\w\b)
```

But .. the results are still very off.

[image]

Examples of good matches:

- foobar
- b4r
- 000
- aaa
- b
- 012345678901234567890123456789 (30)

Examples of bad matches

- täst
- foo bar
- foo_bar
- _bar
- *null*
- 0123456789012345678901234567890 (31)

Comment: Why you want you match this `01234567890123456790123456789 (30)
` ?

Comment: The (30) is an indicator of how long the length is. I will clarify my question.

Comment: you mean `^[a-z0-9]{1,30}\b`

Comment: what language do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `\w`,`\b` and use anchors.

```
^[a-z0-9]{1,30}$
```